# Blender Cycles see inside of transparent object

Tags: transparency

Have problem with transparent object in Cycles render (in Eevee not occurs).
I made some object transparent by adding material with Transparent BSDF shader, but when i set it to make transparent, can see some inside part of it?
I thought it is matter of shadows inside but did not find anything...
Already was trying to plat with settings of material shadows but nothing.
What can be reason of that? i.e. for simple object like plane problem not occurs.
Can be matter of object itself? [image]
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without the file, but maybe, under Blend Mode, disable Show Backface?

Comment: because Moonboots is too nice, i am telling you what you should do (and moonboots just thinks, but doesn't write): share your blend file so we can help you. Your images doesn't help us...

Comment: Here is link to the 3d model which for get the issue https://ufile.io/avwkq12j

Comment: And here is link for the blend file https://ufile.io/4urmu4kz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to increase "Max Bounces" values in "Light Paths" in "Render" tab. You need to increase Total and Transparency values.

It is because you have more than default 8 transparent faces along some of light paths in your scene. When the limit is reached, background color is returned, hence you see black spot there.

Comment: Yes and no, that's more or less correct.

Comment: That fixes an issue. Thanks a lot VaclavC. Beer for you! ;)

Comment: @user135211 Increasing _Total_ bounces isn't necessary. See my detailed answer.  ;)

Comment: @user135211 I just mention it because I want a beer, too.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you have to increase the *Max Bounces* for *Transparency* under *Render Properties* > *Light Paths* - but increasing the *Total* bounces is **not** necessary. The *Transparency* bounces are independent from the *Total* bounces. They need to be increased if you're using a *Transparent BSDF* in your material or for example a *Principled Volume* in smoke simulations.

If you use transmissive materials like a *Glass BSDF* or the *Transmission* in a *Principled BSDF*, then you have to increase the *Transmission* bounces - but this works **only** if you increase the *Total* bounces as well.

[image: light paths]